# How to pass conversation inputs to webhooks using API.AI

Tags: node.js, webhooks, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am new at API.AI and with some tutorial, I get to know how to build a conversational bot type system where your inputs are required one by one to complete the flow like explain in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F68HtCtJbGA). Also, I know there is a concept of getting data from your server using webhooks, I want to learn how to use conversation in chat say in the given example pizza name and type and use these two attributes as parameters for the API.AI's webhook.

API.AI teaches us to build a chat flow model and webhooks used for getting data from the api's but I dont find any way where I could use the data shared in chat to webhooks.

It would be great if I could get some help on this

Answer (score 3):

API.AI calls what you're trying to do "Fulfillment". The fulfillment section of the API.AI console lets you set the URL for the webhook, along with any static headers you may need to make sure this comes from an authentic host.

[image]

Once you have enabled Fulfillment, you'll need to enable that fulfillment for each Intent that you want sent to to by selecting the checkbox at the bottom of the Intent page.

[image]

If you don't see the "Fulfillment" section on your Intent, it usually means you haven't enabled it in the Fulfillment section above. If you see the header, but not the checkboxes, you need to expand that section by clicking on the arrow on the right.

Then you'll need to actually write your webhook. See https://api.ai/docs/fulfillment and https://developers.google.com/actions/apiai/webhook for details.

Comment: Well, for me it was not the right Answer. Actually, what I observed is when I changed the intent to some other intent and check choose webhooks then I should specify the webhooks parameters again in that intent.

Answer (score 0):

I observed that when I changed the old intent to new intent and suppose old intent uses webhooks then in new intent I should check the choose webhooks checkbox and also specify the paramters again for that webhook to be called successfully.